# Counting lines with Flex

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I'm just starting with flex and i have some concerns about this tool.

```
%{
#include "parser.h"
int line_num = 1;
%}

\n { line_num++; } 
%%
```

In the above code i'm just counting the lines in my scanning file, right?

How could I call the line_num value from another .c document? Whit a function like:

`int getLineNumber(void);`

And also, how could I detect lexical errors with this tool? I know that it is with the ".*" pattern but how to print it(in a function on a different .c again) like:

```
printf ("%d: error: %s\n", getLineNumber(), message);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you've shown, you're already defining a global variable `line_num`. Just declare `extern int line_num;` in your header file and you can access it anywhere in your program.

If you want to avoid the global variable, replace the beginning of your scanner with something like:

```
%{
#include "parser.h"

static int line_num = 1;

int getLineNumber(void) {
    return line_num;
}
%}
```

And put a declaration for the `getLineNumber` function in your header. (This is just ordinary C stuff, flex doesn't add anything weird here.)

For error handling, you can add a rule like:

```
.    { reportUnrecognizedToken(); }
```

And then put a function like this somewhere:

```
void uncrecognizedToken() {
   printf("Unrecognized token on line %d\n", getLineNumber());
   exit(1);
}
```

Comment: @adolfosrs I don't quite understand your question. If you want to know which input caused the error, you can examine [the `yytext` and `yyleng` variables](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Matching.html#index-yytext-86).